# Missing synctrl.dll (from Synaptics)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-registry, dll

I wasn't sure whether this ought go on the Security Stack Exchange but it's more to do with a missing .dll and how I can debug an error I've got.

I seem to have an error [shared with other Windows 8 (64-bit) users](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/hp-touchsmart-tm2-wacom/38405-twofingerscroll-v1-0-7-update-two-finger-scrolling-done-right-more-8.html), when trying to add smooth scrolling function in the style of other OSs. My computer doesn't have a `.dll` at `c:\windows\system32\synctrl.dll`, which seems to be the reason the [TwoFingerScroll](https://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/) utility isn't working. Attempting the fix given on [this forum][3]:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe c:\windows\system32\syncom.dll
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe c:\windows\system32\synctrl.dll
```

obviously then gives a module not found error.

Searching through Google brings up

> **SynCtrl.dll : Free .DLL download.**
>
> *DLLme.com* dllme.com/dll/files/synctrl_dll.html‎
>
> Missing SynCtrl.dll? Download this .DLL file for free!

But I'm wary of Trojan horses since I'm using Windows (a website called [webutations says it checks out][4] but still).

I'm only just starting to use the registry (and don't know C++), but am comfortable enough navigating it and have changed basic keys entries etc. when setting Win8 up to debug without much hassle.

Can anyone advise, either what this is doing, whether I can download it somewhere (the Synaptics driver recommended to get this working is v15, but in the current v17 there is no such file). That is I assume it's been dropped in a recent update(?)

Otherwise, can I change some key or other to achieve the desired result (it seems I do indeed need this file though).

*Please let me know if I should provide more details.*

[3]: http: forum.tabletpcreview.com/hp-touchsmart-tm2-wacom/38405-twofingerscroll-v1-0-7-update-two-finger-scrolling-done-right-more-8.html
  [4]: http: www.webutations.org/go/review/dllme.com

Comment: Synaptics has a website which has its device drivers, have you checked there, we can't distribute a single file there are far better places for that sort of activity then Superuser.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if it wasn't clear above but I downloaded v17 and it lacks this dll, but seems to have been in v15, but I can't see older versions of the driver on their site.

Comment: What's the model/manufacturer?

Comment: Acer Aspire E1-571 Synaptics Touchpad Driver 17.0.6.13 for Windows 8.1 64 bit